# Angular.js doesn't start my function twice or something like this

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a function that takes the number (amount) of songs, the object of songs and makes a new object, which includes new amount of songs chosen randomly.
The problem is that when I start it with number of 3, for example, it works correctly, but then I start this function with less number and it shows me the previous result with 3 songs instead of 2. If then I start it with number 5 I want to see 5 new song, but instead I get my previous 3 songs and 2 new. Why It doesn't choose randomly again?

```
$scope.getRandom = function(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
};
$scope.chooseSongs = function(hide) {
  if (hide) {
    $scope.hideDiv();
  }
  if ($scope.number > songs.length) {
    $scope.number = songs.length;
  }
  while ($scope.newSongs.length < $scope.number) {
    $scope.rand = $scope.getRandom(songs.length - 1);
    $scope.songName = songs[$scope.rand].name;
    if ($scope.newSongs.indexOf($scope.songName) == -1) {
      $scope.newSongs.push($scope.songName);
    }
  }
  $scope.number = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `.push` on an array, it does what it says: it "pushes" the new data in the back of the array, ignoring the fact if there already is data or not.

So you never clear your array, and keep "pushing" new data to the back.

An easy solution for this is adding <s>`$scope.newSongs = []`</s> `$scope.newSongs.length = 0;` at the start of your function:

```
$scope.getRandom = function(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1));
};
$scope.chooseSongs = function(hide) {
  $scope.newSongs.length = 0; //$scope.newSongs = [];
  if (hide) {
    $scope.hideDiv();
  }
  if ($scope.number > songs.length) {
    $scope.number = songs.length;
  }
  while ($scope.newSongs.length < $scope.number) {
    $scope.rand = $scope.getRandom(songs.length - 1);
    $scope.songName = songs[$scope.rand].name;
    if ($scope.newSongs.indexOf($scope.songName) == -1) {
      $scope.newSongs.push($scope.songName);
    }
  }
  $scope.number = 1;
};
```

**Edit:** Updated after an interesting comment from Deblaton Jean-Philippe. If you just reassign `$scope.newSongs`, AngularJs won't automatically update the view, if you instead clear the length, it will.

Comment: Linking ``$scope.newSongs`` to a new reference wont help angular to update the view. You should rather use ``$scope.newSongs.length = 0;`` instead of ``$scope.newSongs = [];``

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Thank you, learned something new there. Updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Oh exactly! It was so easy! Thanks :)

Comment: @BenjaminTrepachko No problem. If you found my answer helpful, or if it was 'the' right solution, please feel free to mark it as `answer`.